# Obtaining an elements bindings

Tags: knockout.js

Given a HTML element, how can I determine what bindings are applied to it?

I can determine the bindingContext and viewModel with `ko.dataFor(elem)` and `ko.contextFor(elem)`. Is there something similar that will give me a list of the bindings attached to the element?

At the moment I'm having to use jQuery to figure out what's bound to the element:

```
var bindings = $(element).data("bind");
```

which I then have to manually split up to obtain the key/value pairs for assessment, which is obviously nasty.

```
    bindings= bindings.split(",");

 $.each(bindings, function (index, value) {
    var parts = value.split(":");
    value = parts[1].trim().replace("()", "");

    var observableToUpdate = koElement;
    var propertyParts = value.split(".");

    // The valueAccessor has dots in it? 
    // Let's find the end of this piece of string
    $.each(propertyParts, function (ind, val) {
        observableToUpdate = observableToUpdate[val];
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MR3/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the element and a reference to the binding context then you can use the `getBindings` method of the `ko.bindingProvider` to get the attached binding object.

You can access the current `bindingProvider` through the `ko.bindingProvider.instance` property:

```
var context = ko.contextFor(element);
var bindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings(element, context);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8MR3/).

You can read more about the bindingProviders here: [KO 1.3 Preview Part 2: Custom Binding Providers](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks nemesv. The only issue I'm having now is retrieving the observable that's bound to the binding so I can call valueHasMutated on it. :-|

Comment: As it turns out, I don't need to get the observable because I can just access each binding through `ko.bindingHandlers[bingingName]` and call its `update` method rather than trying to `valueHasMutated`.